# Generate boxplots for a combination of categorical variables

Tags: r, data-visualization, categorical-data, boxplot

How would I do the following?

In a single plot, I would like to create multiple box plots, each X variable being a combination of the categorical variables shown below.

```
data(mtcars)
# y variable is mpg
mtcars$vs  = as.factor(mtcars$vs)
mtcars$cyl = as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean a single plot versus all combinations of the two factors (engine shape (V/S) and cyl), something like so:

```
with(mtcars,boxplot(mpg~interaction(as.factor(ifelse(vs,"S","V")),as.factor(cyl))))
abline(v=c(2.5,4.5),col=8)
```

[image]

(Assuming I have "S" and "V" - for 'straight' and 'vee' engine configurations - the right way around; if the R implementation is consistent with Hocking's 1976 paper - as described on the first page [here](https://ecommons.library.cornell.edu/bitstream/1813/32718/1/BU-619-M.pdf) - I think it should be right)

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like:

```
data(mtcars)
y <- mtcars$mpg
vs <- as.factor(mtcars$vs)
cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(formula = y ~ cyl + vs)
```

Likewise, you could use the `lattice` package this way:

```
require(lattice)

bwplot( ~ y | vs + cyl)
```

Note: the only problem with this style of plot is that the result is, in effect, 6 plots in one (since there are 2 levels for "vs" * 3 for "cyl"). Hence, unless you have enough data available for each possible combination, the resulting plot might not end up looking so good...